# Connection between Wilson loops and fusion rules in $Z_2$ topological order

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, topological-order, anyons, wilson-loop

I'm looking for references (reviews, original articles, lecture notes, etc.) that discuss the connection between the expectation value of Wilson loops (the "disorder parameter" of the system) and anyonic fusion rules. I am familiar with Nayak and co.'s [classic discussion on the topic](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1889), but I am looking for more detailed discussion. E.g.

- How does the average of the Wilson loop effect the conditions on anyon fusion?
- Can we derive fusion rules and superselection sectors by studying the Wilson loop in, say, the Toric code?
- Can people take finite temperature effects into account?

Any reference at the advanced grad level would be welcome.